# Defining a shortcode inside a hook in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode, wordpress-hook

I am currently working on getting a shortcode added via a custom hook in WordPress. I get the data just fine, but the problem occurs when I try to call the shortcode. Since I am not passing a value with the shortcode to use as the parameter in the hook, the code fails and gives me the error `Invalid argument passed to foreach`. Essentially what I want to happen is use a global array in that hook (`$sites`), and not have to use the parameter in my shortcode (shortcode -> `['current-site']`). The `$sites` variable is actually a page here, but the client refers to these as sites. Anybody have an idea of how to accomplish this with the code provided? Is there a better way to do it?

```
<?php
    add_action( 'sst_navigation', 'sst_hook_register_menus', 10, 1 );
    add_action( 'sst_navigation', 'sst_hook_active_navigation', 10, 1 );
    // add_action( 'sst_admin_navigation_hooks', 'sst_hook_set_authentication_links', 10, 3 );


    /* ========== Hooks ========== */
    function sst_hook_register_menus( $sites ) {
        register_nav_menus( $sites );
    }

    function sst_hook_active_navigation( $sites ) {
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $slug = explode( '/', trim( $url, '/' ) );
        $args = array();

        foreach( $sites as $key => $value ) {
            $key = str_replace( '_', '-', $key );

            if( $key === $slug[0] ) {
                $args = array(
                    'theme_location' => $key,
                    'container' => false,
                    'echo' => false,
                    'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
                );

            }
        }
        return strip_tags( wp_nav_menu( $args ), '<a>' );
    }

    function sst_hook_set_authentication_links( $items, $args ) {
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $items .= '<a href="/profile">Profile</a>';
            $items .= '<a class="button primary" href="' . wp_logout_url() . '">Logout</a>';
        } else {
            $items .= '<a class="button primary" href="' . wp_login_url() . '">Login</a>';
        }

        return $items;
    }
?>
```

Comment: To make it more clear, is $sites a page id you are handing over? In your foreach you use 'theme_location' and this looks like a menu object for me. Could you edit your question and add what your shortcode should be doing and how the $sites parameter plays a role in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

To access a global variable inside a function, you have to declare it:

```
global $sites;
```

Or use the GLOBALS array to access it directly, e.g.:

```
$sites = $GLOBALS['sites'];
```